# Translucent navigation + Low profile

Tags: android

We can dim the system bars by using `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE`:

[image]

And we can provide translucent system bars by using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION`.

[image]

However, combining these doesn't work (only one of them is active). Is there a way to achieve the combination of these two effects?

Comment: AFAIK no this isn't possible. But what you should do is hide the System UI instead of dimming it and make it appear when the user interacts with your application in some way. Like Google does it in their new Camera-app for example.

Comment: Thanks @AlexvandenHoogen! My purpose is to show a one-time `Activity` the first time the user starts the app. I don't want to come across blunt by directly going full screen (the app doesn't need full screen at all), but I _do_ want to attract the user's attention to the content (white text on dark gray background), in which dimmed status bars would help a lot.
Too bad it isn't possible. I think I will go with a dimmed status bar and a translucent navigation bar instead.